# Reusable TransitionGroup component doesn't work as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a very simple reusable transition group component. Unfortunattely it doesn't work as expected.

**Expected behavior:** wrap li tag into TransitionGroup --> animation works.

**Actual behavior:** wrap li tag into TransitionGroup and add transition styles into that component --> animation works.

TransitionGroup component:

```
<template>
  <transition-group name="list" tag="ul">
    <slot></slot>
  </transition-group>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 2,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.list-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
}

.list-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.list-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Then I'm trying to use it in ProductList component and it doesn't work:

```
<template>
  <fade-transition-group class="products-list">
    <li
      class="products-list__item"
      v-for="product in productsToRender"
      :key="product.id"
    >
      <card
        :image="product.image"
        :price="product.price"
        :title="product.title"
        :rating="product.rating.rate"
        :id="product.id"
      ></card>
    </li>
  </fade-transition-group>
</template>
```

But if I add transition styles in ProductsList component then it works. Why? How to fix that?

If I add these styles to ProductList component styles section then everything works and it's not clear why:

```
.list-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
}
.list-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;;
}
.list-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: try to remove `scoped`

Comment: This works, thanks! But is it okay to have global styles for transition-group component?

Comment: I would say yes. In my personal project i have an CSS file where i put my transitions in it, and they are globally, so every transition looks the same.